# Unable to change the keyboard shorcuts

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I have installed Oneiric Oncelot. I wanted to change some keyboard shortcuts. So opened System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts. but i am unable to change any ketboard shortcuts. everything is disabled. even the add(+) and remove (-) options are disabled.

am i missing something here. i have installed compiz-settings-manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you highlight a row and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you should be able to set the shortcut. It will change to "New Shortcut..." and wait for you to type something. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will disable it.

[image]

I think you can only use the + and - buttons under the "Custom Shortcuts" section in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks it worked. but wondering why the behavior got changed from earlier version

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut settings can be reached under /apps/metacity/ in `gconf-editor`.

They're also reachable from /home/alice/.gconf/apps/metacity/